# Save cropped image in SQL

Tags: android, sqlite, photo

I would like to save an photo in my SQL database, in a BLOB field. Now I'm doing it saving a byte array, but too much effort for the app to work...I changed the dimensions (BitmapFactory) in order to reduce app work, but the image is a sort of mosaicon and lacks of resolution. Actually I'm taking a photo with the camera and want to save it and use in my DB and App. I know it would be better to save my file path (which would be external SD card) in the DB and retreive the image where I need in my App, but I cannot find clear tutorials to do that. Anyway I would like to save a cropped version of the Photo I take, in order to save more memory. Do you have any clear tutorials to share, or any suggestions about the code to use...thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileSettings.this);
        builder.setTitle("Profile Picture!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, TAKEPIC);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICKPIC);

                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(requestCode==TAKEPIC)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Uri selectedImage =getImageUri(YOURACTIVITY.this,bitmap);

                String localimagepath =getImagePath(YOURACTIVITY.this, selectedImage);


            }
            else if(requestCode==PICKPIC)
            {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                String localimagepath = getImagePath(YOURACTIVITY.this, data.getData());

            }
        }
    }
    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage,"title",null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }


    public  String getImagePath(Context context,Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor =context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null); //managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        else return null;
    }


    public void saveImagePath(String imagePath)
    {
      //push image path to db
      DBHelpher dbHelpher=new DBHelpher(YOURACTIVITY.this);
      dbHelpher.insertImagePath(imagePath);
    }
```

Create class for sqlite to save image path in database

```
public class DBHelpher extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

 Context context;
    public final String TABLE_SAMPLE="test";
      public final String COLUMN_ID="id";
    public final String COLUMN_IMAGEPATH="imagepath";

    public final String CREATE_TABLE__SAMPLE_SQL="create table " + TABLE_SAMPLE
            + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_IMAGEPATH + " text "
            + ");";


    public DBHelpher(Context context)
    {
        super(context, "DATABASENAME.db", null, 1);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE__SAMPLE_SQL);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


    public void insertImagePath(String imagePath)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGEPATH,imagePath);
         database.insert(TABLE_SAMPLE, null, values);


    }


}
```

Call selectImage method from where you want to take a picture.